# getopt in C always returns a 1 or '\001' for every argument

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to use function `getopt()` in C in my code, but it always returns me a 1.

I totally have no idea what happened.
Finally, I shortened my code to a test like this:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int ch;
    while (ch = getopt(argc, argv, "s:E:") != -1) {
        printf(" %d\n", ch);
    }
}
```

Then I ran it with `./test -s 0 -E 1`, I got two 1.
I think I supposed to get at least a 69 for E or something for s?

Here is the screenshot for how I compiled it, run it and even how command line is passed to it with gdb.

[image: result]

At first, I use a 'char ch' instead of 'int ch'. At that time, I will get ch = '/001' from getopt.

## Edit

It works now, it needs brackets.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo calls it!  I'm 100% sure. The assignment op has a lower priority than the relational one. C _does_ have too many priorities, but they are at least pretty reasonable.

Comment: When some answer helps you, [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Don't modify the question to say that it has been solved. And don't use images here except when it's really necessary. Just copy the text and paste here

Answer (score 4):

```
ch = something != -1
```

[is equivalent to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

```
ch = (something != -1)
```

Thus, you don't actually get the result of `getopt` call in `ch`, but rather the result of the comparison (which is true when the loop body get's executed, thus `1`).

To fix this, add an extra pair of parentheses:

```
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argvm "s:E:")) != -1) {
    printf(" %d\n", ch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (ch = getopt(argc, argv, "s:E:") != -1)
```

Is parsed as:

```
while (ch = (getopt(argc, argv, "s:E:") != -1))
```

I.e. compare the result of `getopt` and store the comparison result (either a 1 or 0) in `ch`.

Use parenthesis to override the order of operations:

```
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "s:E:")) != -1)
```